# How to implement only one user can access a certain the page - MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, restriction

I have a page for editing product details. I want to restrict that only one user can edit the product page. When a new user opens it while there is a current user editing it, I would like to place some notification then automatically make it available once the current user leaves the page. Any suggestion on how I should approach this?

Comment: This is generally thought to be a bad idea.  You are asking to take out a server-wide lock.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just letting them both edit at the same time.

If you want to notify the last person to save their document, then you can add a "version" column to the database.

Upon saving, you would check the version column, to ensure that the row had not been changed.  If it had been changed, you would notify the user at that point.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you question correctly it sounds like you need to know about database concurrency,
Here are a couple of articles:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213031%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
[Ironspeed](http://www.ironspeed.com/Designer/8.0.2/WebHelp/Part_VIII/What_is_Pessimistic_Concurrency.htm)

Now if you are asking how to authorize only a single user to edit records then you would need to look at roles and aloow say only admins to edit records.

Comment: He is trying to serialize access to a particular web page, for editing a particular database entity.  I believe that he wishes to prevent the situation where two people are editing the same object at the same time.

Comment: Thanks ashok and John. John is right that I want to prevent the situation where two people are editing. My last resort is to use concurrency. I just want to lessen the hassle for the user when there is concurrency conflicts. So when they open the edit page, they are already notified that someone is editing it.

Answer (score 0):

you can have optimistic lock on your record while it is in edit mode , once it is saved make that record avaliable for other user.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Create a table something like userAccess with IsAccessColumn

if user 1 access edit page set isAccess to True

So the second user will not access the edit page if records is set to true.

Then Set to False if user 1 finally edited the record

After that user 2 can now open edit page.

Regards